# Obtener datos de posicionamiento de un mapa web

Tags: json, scraping

Existe esta página que contiene en tiempo real la ubicación de líneas de buses:

https://www.montevideo.gub.uy/buses/mapaBuses.html

He consultado y al día de hoy no proporcionan una api que permita hacer las consultas de posición de cada bus.

En la pagina, los datos del mapa se completan con consultas https que tienen una respuesta json del tipo:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "id": "stm.pck:50:empresa:4016:variante:440:bus",
                "codigoEmpresa": 50,
                "frecuencia": 90,
                "codigoBus": 440,
                "variante": 4016,
                "linea": "169",
                "sublinea": "ADUANA---TOLEDO CHICO",
                "tipoLinea": 2,
                "tipoLineaDesc": "Urbana",
                "destino": 71,
                "destinoDesc": "INSTRUCCIONES Y JOSÉ BELLONI",
                "subsistema": 1,
                "subsistemaDesc": "Montevideo",
                "version": 1,
                "velocidad": 32
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -56.186832,
                    -34.89247
                ]
            }
        }
```

En la cual se puede obtener el dato de la posición y velocidad. Esos datos los utiliza para actualizar el mapa.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me interesa poder obtener el dato de posición de 3 líneas en particular para poder generar una alerta cuando el bus se encuentre a 10 minutos de mi parada.

Dado que no hay una api, de que forma podría "leer" la respuesta json que se carga en el mapa de la página?

Muchas gracias por cualquier idea!